# Android-SDK emulator doesn't receive my changes on JS source

Tags: android, emulation

I have been trying to develop a simple application to android.

Environment is Windows 7, 64 bit

Steps, which I follow:

- I start Gvim and open index.android.js file (this contains the whole application source)
- I run emulator with AVD Manager (emulator starts successfully)
- I run react-native run-android

I test my application, repair errors on index.android.js, and press Reload JS

These work for a while, but after some time if I refresh the application with Reload JS button, it doesn't receive my changes of source JS code.

I tried:
-restart emulator
-uninstall and reinstall my application
-delete index.android.js file :)
but don't help.

Is there an cache of source js file somewhere? Or is it an other problem?
thanks